# How Can I Limit The Amount of Data Received In WebRTC Datachannel

Tags: javascript, webrtc, p2p

I need some protection in a WebRTC APP, i need to stop clients receiving a large data packet, eg 2kb.

I need to cut of so to speak if someone sends me data larger than 2kb and delete the message. is there a setting somewhere i can limit the data received. or can i intercept the data while being downloaded, then stop the download part way.

Iv been searching around but could not find any information on this.

Comment: afaik, no, there's not, but i'd also love to be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As per Mozilla foundation WebRTC site that describes [Using WebRTC data channels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Using_data_channels) there is not.

> WebRTC data channels support buffering of outbound data. This is handled automatically. While there's no way to control the size of the buffer, you can learn how much data is currently buffered, and you can choose to be notified by an event when the buffer starts to run low on queued data. This makes it easy to write efficient routines that make sure there's always data ready to send without over-using memory or swamping the channel completely.

However, if your intention is to use the data received as a trigger, you may be able to use *RTCDataChannel.bufferedAmount*.
This returns the number of bytes of data currently queued to be sent over the data channel. More details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCDataChannel/bufferedAmount).

Get that value and build a logic to limit or stop download as per your needs.

**Syntax**

```
var amount = aDataChannel.bufferedAmount;
```